# MATLAB linprog max iterations reached

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I had written the following matlab code to optimize the following LP

```
  max b'x
  s.t A'x <= 0;
      x <= d;
```

Also d is

```
 d = {1,2..m}
```

and A is defined in the code. I am getting the error:

```
Maximum number of iterations exceeded; increase options.MaxIter.
```

Upon googling, someone said it is not very good that the error is occuring. and the problem has to reformulated. Any idea how to reformulate it.

The solution is very simple as A > 0, b> 0 and d>0 therefore x = 0

```
m   = 10;

d = [1:1:m];

for j = 1:m,
    for i = 1:m,
        A(i,j) = 1/(i+j-1);
    end
end
for i = 1:m,
    b(i)=0;
end
for i = 1:m
    lb(i) = -inf;
end
b;
lb = lb';

f = A*d';
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = linprog(-f,A,b,[],[],lb,d); %minimzation problem. Hence -f, A = A'
```

Comment: Consider to use the Opti-Toolbox: http://www.i2c2.aut.ac.nz/Wiki/OPTI/

Comment: hmmm, when I run your code on matlab 2010b, I get this error: "Exiting: One or more of the residuals, duality gap, or total relative error
 has stalled:
         the dual appears to be infeasible (and the primal unbounded).      
         (The primal residual < TolFun=1.00e-008.)"

Comment: Do you want to try the Simplex approach and see what you get? use something like optimset('LargeScale','off','Simplex','on');

Comment: I have very little knoledge about `linprog`, but are you sure your matrices are the right size? because `lingprog` tries to solve `f'*x`, and in your code that is undefined. Being `A` 10x10, I am wondering if you have made some mistake in the shapes of the matrices and you havent noticed....

Comment: I mean.... Your lower boundary and upper boundary are not the same size.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd used the optimist = ('MaxIter', 10000). To stop that error message.